# How to create database for multi-level menu, category and right-side content

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I trying to rewrite the website (it is same as https://ketoansaovang.com.vn/en/news/accounting-news-1.html) by Django. I have problem with design database for main menu and other part of page. For example, "NEWS AND EVENT" item have subitem as "ACCOUNTING NEWS", "AUDIT NEWS", "TAX NEWS",... When I choose one sub-item, it is highlighted on left category and ringt show all news for this subitem. [workflow when click on news sub-item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpuHH.png)

I have designed menu model as below:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    menu_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None,  blank=True, null=True)
    menu_title = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique=True)
    menu_link = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_title
```

But I can not link it to news or services item.
Please give idea for it.

Comment: I don't understand.
You are putting frontend components in database? (I'm talking about your menus)

Comment: Because I want menu to be able extend on future. And I see relationship of sub-item menu and right-side content (Only one template for item and sub-item, example as "NEWS AND EVENT" item and  "ACCOUNTING NEWS", "AUDIT NEWS", "TAX NEWS" sub-item). How can I use one template for item and sub-item menu?

Comment: You say you can't link it to News or Services. These are 'Menu' objects too ? Or they are other models ?

Comment: News and Services are model classes!

Comment: Yes..I was asking if News and Services were Menus too.. Then just add another ForeignKey to these models.

Comment: Your opinion is we have one model for both News and Services. News and Services are only different on user interface. If I mind true, I can try to do it. But how I can limit chosen ForiegnKey only with sub-item for each News or Services entry on admin page, because rule is not have relation between item and content (a news or service).

Comment: I didn't say that. It is not my opinion. I was just asking. I don't even know why you want to create a models for your menus that will just be links.. Something that is purely visual and that is usually done in your template. Please provide your use case. Why do you need your menus as a database model ?

Comment: I resolve it as your way. I add ForeignKey to News and Service model. Then I limit data show on admin page of News and Services by override formfield_for_foreignkey() (link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey). For example, News only show news sub-item (such as "ACCOUNTING NEWS", "AUDIT NEWS", "TAX NEWS", ...)

Comment: Okay I see your use case now. Then yes just link your models with ForeignKeys as I said and limit the choices as you did.